# matplotlibでのグラフの形状の変え方

Tags: python, matplotlib

columnsのラベルが450から900まで5刻みのデータフレームがあります(indexは200まで)．それを25間隔で取得してグラフにしました．このグラフの形を正方形にするにはどうしたらいいですか？
以下にコードを記します．

```
for i in range(450,901,25):
    fig=plt.figure()
    data.plot(y=["%d"%(i)],
              color="blue",
             )
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんな感じでどうでしょうか？

```
for i in range(450,901,25):
    ax=plt.subplot(aspect='equal')
    data.plot(y=["%d"%(i)], color="blue", ax=ax)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: 出来ました．ありがとうございました．